# Grep with regex in CLI returns nothing

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have the following file.

```
//TESTCASES=3
//MARK=9

[runscript]
nc dec s10 s11
[/runscript]

[checks]

[/checks]

[testcase]
// List: 1, 2, 3, 5, 0xA, -1
.global LIST
.data
LIST: 
.word 1, 2, 3, 5, 0xA, -1
[/testcase]
```

I am trying to get the text between `[runscript]` and `[/runscript]` using grep and regex.

I have verified that the regex works on its own.

```
(?<=\[runscript\]\n)(.|\n)*(?=\[\/runscript\])
```

However, grep returns nothing. Is it an issue of the options? I have tried many of them alone and combined.

-P, -e, -E, -w, -o

What am I missing?

Comment: Related: [grep with line breaks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361703/grep-with-line-breaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `grep` but rather `awk`:

```
awk '
    $0=="[runscript]" {rs++; next}
    $0=="[/runscript]" {rs--}
    rs {print}
' file
```

Output

```
nc dec s10 s11
```

If you really want to use `grep`, this will work with PCREs and NUL-delimited data. But I would suggest it's harder for people to understand (and maintain) then the `awk` version, and less portable too:

```
grep -zoP '(?<=\[runscript\]\n)(.|\n)*?(?=\[\/runscript\])' file
```

Output (with an invisible trailing NUL)

```
nc dec s10 s11
```

I've tweaked your RE to cope with multiple matches should there be any.

Comment: +1 even if the question was about grep :)

Comment: @Emmanuel version with `grep` added for completeness

Comment: I am pasting the exact command, yet output is completely empty. I tried it with grep 3.6 and 3.7, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @vic file generated on Windows? Not GNU `grep`?

Comment: @roaima You're dead right.

Comment: Beware there's a NUL character at the end of `grep`'s output. It also assumes there's only one matching section per file (the `*` should probably be `*?`).

Answer (score 3):

`grep` works on one line at a time, so the thing the regex is matched against will never contain a newline character.

Since you want to use perl/PCRE operators, you could use `pcregrep` which has a multi-line mode with `-M` and can be told to report part of a match:

```
pcregrep -xMo1 '(?s)\[runscript\]\n(.*?)\n\[/runscript]'
```

Or:

```
pcregrep -xMo1 '(?s)\[runscript\]\r?\n(.*?)\n\[/runscript]\r?'
```

To allow MS-DOS style CRLF line delimiters (here the CRs are included in the output if present in the input).